# Only install to a empty directory

Tags: install4j

I notice that when installer launches it detects a previous installation and prompts me if I want to update it. Is there anyway to disable this behavior?

I have an application that always needs to be installed into a clean empty directory. Are there any controls in install4j for doing this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To just remove the update alert, locate the "Welcome" screen on the Installer->Screens & Actions step and deselect the "Alert for update installation" property.

To prevent the installer from suggesting the previous installation directory, deselect  "Detect previous installation directory" on the Installer->Update Options step.

To prevent installation on top of an existing installation (i.e. no updates will be possible), set the "Validation expression" property of the "Installation location" screen to

```
File dir = context.getInstallationDirectory();
if (ApplicationRegistry.getApplicationInfoByDir(dir) != null) {
    Util.showWarningMessage(
        "The selected directory already contains an installation, "+
        "please choose another directory."
    );
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I just tried doing this for a Linux installer and it looks like the getInstallationDirectory() doesn't point to the correct path if the user modifies the installation path, it always points to the installer default.

This means that if the user first installed the product in a custom path and then tries to do a reinstall in that path no warning will be shown and everything will be overwritten.

Comment: Maybe "Detect previous installation directory" on the Installer->Update Options step is deselected.

Comment: yes, it is deselected (just as instructed in the answer above); I've seen that it works with it selected, but that then means that if the user has two installations and then does a third one over the first one it'll overwrite it, as the getInstallationDirectory points to the second reinstall. What I'm asking is if it's possible to update the InstallationDirectory variable with what the user chooses in the GUI without moving the validation to a separate page.